# Adapter referencing generated classes (android-sunflower)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am looking at a `Kotlin` sample app by Google called [Sunflower](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower) that I am using to understand how `Kotlin` / `Android Jetpack` works.

In `PlantAdapter` is the following code:

```
/**
 * Adapter for the [RecyclerView] in [PlantListFragment].
 */
class PlantAdapter : ListAdapter<Plant, PlantAdapter.ViewHolder>(PlantDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val plant = getItem(position)
        holder.apply {
            bind(createOnClickListener(plant.plantId), plant)
            itemView.tag = plant
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(ListItemPlantBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    private fun createOnClickListener(plantId: String): View.OnClickListener {
        return View.OnClickListener {
            val direction = PlantListFragmentDirections.ActionPlantListFragmentToPlantDetailFragment(plantId)
            it.findNavController().navigate(direction)
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(
        private val binding: ListItemPlantBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(listener: View.OnClickListener, item: Plant) {
            binding.apply {
                clickListener = listener
                plant = item
                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am confused about is where it gets `PlantListFragmentDirections` and `ListItemPlantBinding`? When I jump to the definition of these classes, they are in the `build` folder where it is autogenerated. When I look at the imports

- `import
  com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.PlantListFragmentDirections`
- `import
  com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.databinding.ListItemPlantBinding`

They are not in the project structure. How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different kinds generated classes. They are generated automatically during the build (and on the fly when using Android Studio). The naming follow the names that are defined in .xml resource files with a suffix corresponding to their component.

**1.** `ListItemPlantBinding`

`ListItemPlantBinding` is a class generated for data-binding, see [generated data-binding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding)

> The above layout filename is **activity_main.xml** so the corresponding generated class is **ActivityMainBinding**

This means `ListItemPlantBinding` is generated for [list_item_plant.xml](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/list_item_plant.xml)

Data-binding is enabled by

```
dataBinding {
     enabled = true
}
```

in [build.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/356b192d38900f638e985cc293b0020fced2870d/app/build.gradle#L26)

**2.** `PlantListFragmentDirections`

[Navigation Architecture Component docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) points to the second answer.

> A class for the destination where the action originates, appended with the word "Directions".

Therefore `PlantListFragmentDirections` originates from [nav_garden.xml](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/356b192d38900f638e985cc293b0020fced2870d/app/src/main/res/navigation/nav_garden.xml#L30):

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/plant_list_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.PlantListFragment"
    android:label="@string/plant_list_title"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_plant_list">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_plant_list_fragment_to_plant_detail_fragment"
        app:destination="@id/plant_detail_fragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
</fragment>
```

Note the `<fragment>` element with the enclosed `<action>`

For how to enable navigation please refer to [Navigation Architecture Component docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing)

Comment: very interesting. I appreciate the detailed explanation!